# get the co-ordinates of draggable div even after changing its position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div which is draggable and i am getting the left and top co-ordinates of the div after clicking in it and storing the values of the two co-ordinates in two hidden fields.
My question is that when ever i change the position of the div the value of co-ordinates present in the hidden field are not changing.The value remains the same as when the div was clicked for the 1st time.
Please kindly help how to get the value of co-ordinates after changing the position of the div.
Thanks in advance.
Below is my code..
    $('.class1').on('click',function (e) {
    var x = (e.pageX -this.offsetLeft), y=(e.pageY -this.offsetTop);

```
    var text1="<div class='tip'><input type='hidden' name='setting[ftype][]' class='ftype' value='1' />\n\
```

"+
            ""+

\n\
\n\
' alt='delete' style='width:20px;' />";

```
     var text2="<div class='tip'><input type='hidden' name='setting[ftype][]' class='ftype' value='2' />\n\
```

"+
            ""+""+

Initials\n\
\n\
' alt='delete' style='width:20px;' />";

```
     var text3="<div class='tip'><input type='hidden' name='setting[ftype][]' class='ftype' value='3' />\n\
```

"+
            ""+"
\n\
\n\
\n\
' alt='delete' style='width:20px;' />";

```
     var text4="<div class='tip'><input type='hidden' name='setting[ftype][]' class='ftype' value='4' />\n\
```

"+
            ""+""+

\n\
Checkbox\n\
\n\
' alt='delete' style='width:20px;' />";

```
     var text5="<div class='tip'><input type='hidden' name='setting[ftype][]' class='ftype' value='5' />\n\
```

"+
            ""+""+

\n\
\n\
\n\
' alt='delete' style='width:20px;' />";

```
    if($('#setBtn').val()!=''){ 
       if($('#setBtn').val()==5){
          t=text5;
       }else if($('#setBtn').val()==4){
           t=text4;
       }else if($('#setBtn').val()==3){
           t=text3;
       }else if($('#setBtn').val()==2){
           t=text2;
       }else{
           t=text1;
       }

        $('<div />', {
          'class': ' ui-widget-content',             
          html: t,             
          appendTo: '.class1',
          draggable: {
              containment: 'parent',
              stop : function(){ 

             }
          },
         resizable:{
         }
      }).css({
          "position" : "absolute",
          "top" : y,
          "left" : x
      }).on('click','.draggable,.tip',function (e1) {
       e1.stopPropagation();
      }).on('click','.deleteS',function (e2) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
       e2.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
});
```